# ajax post triggering twice

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

In an asp.net mvc3 application there is a form. Form is posted via jquery post. Below is the related code.

```
                $(this).find('form').live('submit', function () {
                    var request = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                       //do something    
                    });
                    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                       //do something    
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

live() is used because form is loaded via ajax and I didn't want to bind click event each time form is retrieved via ajax.

The problem is clicking submit causes form to be posted twice. Tested in chrome and IE9, occurs in both of them.

- I checked if page contains any other forms but there is only 1 form.
- I disabled all the extensions in both browsers (firebug might cause this)
- There aren't any resources on page causing 404 (ie images).

So what else may cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are bining the form, or the submit button twice. There is a [bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) called Visual Event (not mine). Run in a check if this is the case. As kaz said without the actual html not much can be done

Comment: it's binded twice as you said. nasty bug was it. good prediction :)

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell without html markup, maybe you have two nested forms?

Try with event.stopPropagation or preventDefault:

```
$(this).find('form').live('submit', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var request = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                    });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                       //do something    
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: what about: $(this).find('form').unbind('submit').live('submit', (...)

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me. I had an Ajax form and the only thing I got to work was:

```
$('#docForm').ajaxForm({

  ...Do Some Mildly Cool Stuff Code...

}).submit(function (e) {
  return false;
}); //Just add the submit to the end.
```

And that was all it took.

Hope it helps!